# Matlab: how to write cell array of matrices to file

Tags: matlab, cell, cell-array

i have a cell of several matrices (all double and with the same dimension)

```
my_cell = 

    [172x15 double]    [172x15 double]    [172x15 double]    [172x15 double]
```

I would to write the matrices on txt file side by side and tabulated, to obtain a .txt file with 172 rows and 60 columns (in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [dlmwrite](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) and [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

```
mat = cell2mat(my_cell);
delimiter = ' ';  % // used to separate two values in a row in the file
filename  = 'test.txt';
dlmwrite(filename,mat,delimiter);
```

Comment: ok, thank you. If I would to select only some columns of the matrices? Do you have an idea? Should I open a new topic?

Comment: I tried with: mat = cell2mat(my_cell(i)); my_mat = mat(1:end, 1:12);dlmwrite(filename,mat,delimiter); but the file is overwritten by the i-mat

Comment: @Mixo make a new matrix using `cat` as `new_mat = cat(2,mat(:,col_start1:col_end1),mat(:,col_start2:col_end2),.....);`
and if you want to select only some columns then I believe you want to store it in a new file. But if you want to append the earlier file then use `dlmwrite('my_earlier_File.txt',new_mat,'-append',...
'delimiter',' ');`

Answer (score 2):

```
>> dlmwrite('file1.txt', [c{:}],'delimiter','\t','precision','%.5f')
```

or

```
>> dlmwrite('file2.txt', c(:)','delimiter','\t','precision','%.5f')
```

You have to choose a precision, otherwise you'll get non-uniform lines because of different numbers of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
%// output_filepath is the name of your output text file

c1 = horzcat(my_cell{:})
datacell = mat2cell(c1,ones(1,size(c1,1)),ones(1,size(c1,2)))
dlmwrite(output_filepath,datacell,'\t'); %// a TAB delimiter is used
```